# Do patent citation degrees follow a power-law?

Tags: r, igraph, power-law

I'm currently working on a thesis on patent citation networks.
Most approaches are based upon the hypothesis that the degrees, specifically the in-degrees (forward citations) follow a power-law distribution, thus making the network scale-free.
For some datasets this is true (e.g. herbicide patents), but for other it isn't (e.g. mrna technology patents). I've seen many works that either use this or ignore the fact that the vertices degrees don't follow a power law distribution.
I don't see many works expanding on how to determine this with a strong statistical approach.

- Are other distributions compatible with scale-free networks?
- Also, one of my datasets change from not following a power-law to following if I normalize the degrees. Can someone help me understand this feature? I'm using the function fit_power_law() from iGraph in RStudio to verify it.

Below are some features of my dataset:
Number of nodes: 7388
Number of edges: 23259
is.dag() = TRUE
is.connected() = FALSE

I get a good power-law fit for all degree values in log, but if they're not in log I only get a good power-law fit for degrees > 34 (given by the same function as an approximation to the minimum degree that will generate the greater p-value according to maximum-likelihood statistic)

Comment: Probably the best starting-point to answer this question is "Power-law distributions in empirical data" by
Aaron Clauset, Cosma Rohilla Shalizi, M. E. J. Newman. https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062

Comment: I'll note that the documentation of [`fit_power_law()`](https://r.igraph.org/reference/fit_power_law.html), which OP said they were using, references that very paper, as well as more. Yet OP says, "I don't see many works expanding on how to determine this with a strong statistical approach."